# Abelian group structure and structure of Z[i]

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $F = \Bbb{Z_p}$. For which prime integers $p$ does the additive group $F^1$ have a structure of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$-module? How about for $F^2$?

I'm not really sure on how to approach this question, do I incorporate direct sum of cyclic groups into this? I'm very lost so any help at all will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Is it the integers mod $p$ or is it the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: integers mod $p$

Answer (score 2):

A $\mathbb Z[i]$-module structure on $F$ is the same as a ring map $\mathbb Z[i] \to \operatorname{End}(F)$.

We have $Z[i] = \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$, i.e. a ring map $\mathbb Z[i] \to \operatorname{End}(F)$ is the same as a ring map $\mathbb Z[X] \to \operatorname{End}(F)=F$, which maps $X$ to an element, which satisfies $x^2+1=0$.

Hence $F=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ admits a $\mathbb Z[i]$-module structure if and only if $-1$ is a square. I think you already know for which primes this holds.